# Getting the user's default browser in Java

Tags: java, browser

I want to know how to get the location of the user's default Internet browser in Java. How can I get this? I would prefer it as a URI to the browser's executable file. Must work cross-platform.

Comment: I'm betting that this is completely impossible from an applet. If you're talking about a Java program, well, to make it work cross-platform would be challenging to say the least.

Comment: .... thanks? This is pretty much why I asked such a knowledgeable community. This site usually gives useful answers.

Comment: The big question is: "why?". This sounds more like as if you're asking how to achieve a solution of which you thought that it's the right solution for a certain problem (but which is after all not), instead of just elaborating about the actual problem. If all you after all want is to let it open a webpage, then yes, use `Desktop#browse()` as suggested by camickr.

Comment: I want to log their default browser and hopefully its installed location in my log file

Comment: to help me better understand the environment in which they are operating my program in the event that they must report an  error.

Comment: So, a webbrowser is involved in your program? How about an error reporting form in flavor of a HTML form, open it by `Desktop#browse()` and then just sniff `User-Agent` header in server side upon submit?

Comment: ... wait what? I don't get what you mean. No browser is involved as of yet, but this is a utility class I am planning on using in ALL of my programs in the future.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get at all why this information is so important for you that you'd like to break Java's crossplatform ideology. Anyway, I'm still lost in this one. Good luck solving the problem :)

Comment: So you don't have a web server... but you _do_ want to know what browser your clients are using... and exactly how do you plan to retrieve that information from the client?

Comment: Obviously Java can do that, because Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("")); opens the specified URL in the default browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The safest thing you can do is something like this:

```
if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) 
{
  Desktop.getDesktop().browse("your url here");
}
```

more info on the Desktop class (mail, print, edit, etc) [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html)

Comment: changing this to accepted answer because it has a usable example

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the Desktop class for this. This is the cross platform API that will invoke the default browser.

Answer (score 1):

> I would prefer it as a URI to the browser's executable file.

From your comments, I assume that you want this information when the user visits your site with his / her web browser.  If so, the answer is that the information is not available unless you can convince the user to install a trusted browser plugin / addon or run a trusted applet.

The reason is that it would be a security breach for an untrusted web page to be able to get this information.  It reveals information about the user's personal preferences, and potentially makes it easier for hackers to target the user's browser and compromise his / her machine.

The best you can do is look at the HTTP request's UserAgent header.  This may be inaccurate, but that is the user's perogative.

Comment: it's an offline Java application. No website is visited, as of yet.

Comment: Even so, the privacy and security concerns remain valid.  When I install an application on my machine, I DO NOT want it calling back to tell the application developer about how my machine is configured.

Comment: No browser is involved as of yet, but this is a utility class I am planning on using in ALL of my programs in the future.

Comment: (Note to self - never install one of @Supuhstar's applications.)

Comment: I just want to know "Opera" or "Firefox", etc. How is this so dangerous?

Comment: It is potentially dangerous because someone can then target an exploit against the user's actual browser. You also wanted to know the path to the browser which can potentially be exploited in other ways.

Comment: But the real point is that you are invading the user's privacy.  And THAT is why I won't use one of your applications.  The information you are trying to extract is *none of your business* as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: well, then, you'll be clad to know I won't even try to do this. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: In fact, yes I am glad to know that.  You have made a wise decision, IMO.